# how to get RouteName in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, routes

I want to get current route Name that is being used in current url in middleware. i tried many example that nothing is working. please share best way to get that route name in Middleware.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Closure;

class PermissionMiddleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $pemissions = getUserPermissions($user);
        session(['permissions' => $pemissions]);

        $defaultPermission = $this->defaultPermission($user->user_type, $user->is_super);
        $defaultPermission[] ='admin';
        
        session(['defaultPermission' => $defaultPermission]);
         return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get route name from current request

```
$request->route()->getName()
```

or

```
 request()->route()->getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->route()->getName()
```